# Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360 file transfer, USB not recognised. No USB options in Settings menu

Tags: usb, file-transfer, windows, samsung-galaxy-y, mtp

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360 and I wish to transfer some audio files from it to my PC, running Windows 8.

When I connect the phone to the computer with the USB cable, the phone beeps and begins charging but displays no USB connection notification. Likewise, the computer doesn't register the connection at all. I have googled the problem but only seem to find partial solutions, which don't fit my situation.

I've tried updating PC drivers and phone software, turning off and on again, trying with and without Kies software and on several different machines.

The phone is running Android 2.3.6

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Some USB cables don't include the data wires as they are only meant for charging. Check if other devices work with this cable, and try another cable.
Also, if the cable is sure to work, take a look at My computer -> right click -> Manage -> Device manager and see if you can find your phone there and try upgrading the driver from there.

Answer (score -1):

Just got to Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging and confirm that usb debugging is disabled. That is it. Now your phone will connect to PC perfect.