# GT-S6810L Driver for Samsung Galaxy Ace II needs to be installed each time device is plugged in my PC

Tags: windows, usb-drivers, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace II *that for a unknown reason*, each time that I plug my smartphone *via USB cable* to my PC, most of the times, my device is not recognized.

When is not recognized, I have to follow this steps:

- Open *device manager*
- Select *portatil devices*.
- Select the driver *that has the warning sign* > Update driver

And *between 20 segs - 1 minute* later, I receive this message *(in Spanish)*:

*Basically it says that the driver for my device was **installed**:*
[image: Updated driver for Samsung Galaxy Ace II]

The problem that I have is *kind of* similiar to [these](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/70304) [questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/67651).

My PC is a Windows 7 Professional - 32 bits.

I bought My Samsung Galaxy Ace II more than a year ago and it wasn't rooted or any similar changes to its system.

---

After check the Register *as says in this [source](https://youtu.be/ls70hsPNqHQ?t=114)*, I can't find the *upperFilter* entry. I really don't know what else can be done.

I already installed Samsung Kies *as suggested in his [comment #1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155454/gt-s6810l-driver-for-samsung-galaxy-ace-ii-needs-to-be-installed-each-time-devic#comment199318_155454)*, but my device isn't compatible with Kies.

Windows Update *sometimes* finds and installs **Device MTP USB** missing driver, but when is not found, I can't plug my device in my PC.

**What could be the cause of this behavior?**

Comment: Does it connect through Kies/ smart switch ?

Comment: @beeshyams, no I don't _I just use the USB cable that comes with the device and plug it to my PC_ - no external software driver that I'm aware of.

Comment: You can see if installation of this driver helps https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH

Comment: Also installing Kies helps sometimes, since it comes with drivers that help recognise the device

Comment: @beeshyams I'll try once I get access to my PC again, thank you. If the links that you provided works, I'll tell you for add it as an answer.

Comment: Kies you can download from Samsung web site. Please try that also. All the best

Answer (score 0):

you can update your Ace driver via right clicking on it and click on update. but if it doesn't work download the BIOS drivers with your web browser by entering your PC name and model then BIOS on google. and try updating from device manager